# Connect to secure webservice in Android using KSoap2

Tags: android, web-services, security, ksoap2

I'm trying to connect to a secure webservice in an Android app using KSoap2, but having some difficulty. I've looked at a few tutorials and other questions/answers on StackOverflow but so far nothing has worked.

I have an identical webservice on an unsecure service, and I can connect to this just fine. I am not sure if I need to setup an SSL connection manually or if KSoap2 should handle all that, when using the secure service?

I'm trying to use the solution found [here](https://gist.github.com/908048) but I'm getting the following error:

```
java.io.IOException: Relative path:  
https://XXXXXXXX.net/FPSecureService/ClientService.svc
```

When using SoapUI I can connect to the secure webservice no problem - I have to set a username and password and WSS-Password Type to "PasswordText", and then it works fine. I have tried to get my Java code to mimic the SoapUI-generated request code as best I can. All the header stuff I'm adding is to try to make it identical to the SoapUI-generated request, but this hasn't worked.

Here is the my code calling the web service:

public void secureWebServiceCall() {

```
    // secure service
    String mUrl = "https://XXXXXXXX.net/FPSecureService/ClientService.svc"; 

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME); 

    String clientID = "XXXXXXX";

    PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
    pi.setName("nationalID"); 
    pi.setValue(clientID); 
    pi.setType(clientID.getClass()); 
    request.addProperty(pi);

    // build Envelope
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11); 
    envelope.dotNet = true;

    // Apdd mapping and marshalling
    envelope.addMapping(NAMESPACE, "GetClientByNationalID", new ClientID().getClass());
    Marshal floatMarshal = new MarshalFloat();
    floatMarshal.register(envelope); 


    // Construct soap envelope headers
    Element[] header = new Element[1];
    header[0] = new Element().createElement("http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd","Security");
    header[0].setAttribute(null, "mustUnderstand","1");
    Element usernametoken = new Element().createElement("http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd", "UsernameToken");
    usernametoken.setAttribute("http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd", "Id", "UsernameToken-1");
    header[0].addChild(Node.ELEMENT,usernametoken);
    Element username = new Element().createElement(null, "n0:Username");
    username.addChild(Node.TEXT, "XXXXXXXX");
    usernametoken.addChild(Node.ELEMENT, username);
    Element pass = new Element().createElement(null, "n0:Password");
    pass.setAttribute(null, "Type", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText");
    pass.addChild(Node.TEXT, "XXXXXXX");
    usernametoken.addChild(Node.ELEMENT, pass);
    Element nonce = new Element().createElement(null, "n0:Nonce"); 
    nonce.setAttribute(null, "EncodingType", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary");
    nonce.addChild(Node.TEXT, "eic5EdyTomcBLocwyph5Mw==");
    usernametoken.addChild(Node.ELEMENT, nonce);
    Element created = new Element().createElement(null, "n0:Created");
    created.addChild(Node.TEXT, "2012-02-08T09:47:55.225Z");
    usernametoken.addChild(Node.ELEMENT, created); 

    envelope.headerOut = header; 

    // Set Output Soap Object as Request
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request); 
    HttpTransportSE t = new HttpTransportSE(mUrl);
    AndroidInsecureKeepAliveHttpsTransportSE androidTransport = 
new AndroidInsecureKeepAliveHttpsTransportSE("XXXXXXXX.net", 80, mUrl, 50000);


    ClientID client = new ClientID(); 
    t.debug = true; 

    try { 
        Log.i("webServiceCall", "Trying call to web service");
        // t.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        androidTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope); 
        SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1); 
        tv.setText(response.getPropertyAsString(3)); 

        Log.i("success", response.getPropertyAsString(0)); 
        Log.i("success", response.getPropertyAsString(1));
        Log.i("success", response.getPropertyAsString(2));
        Log.i("success", response.getPropertyAsString(3));
        Log.i("success", response.getPropertyAsString(4)); 
        System.out.println("Request: "  + t.requestDump); 
        System.out.println("Response: " + t.responseDump);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("webServiceCall", "Error calling webservice.");
        e.printStackTrace(); 
        System.out.println("Request: "  + t.requestDump); 
        System.out.println("Response: " + t.responseDump);
    }

}
```

Does anyone have any ideas? I felt like I might be finally getting somewhere with the AndroidInsecureHttpsServiceConnection and all that SSL stuff, but it doesn't work. I can't help feeling I've made a simple mistake somewhere but I don't know what it is. That "Relative path" error makes me feel like it's something very simple to do with the paramaters I'm giving the connection, but I'm new to that stuff and not sure what parameters I should be specifying and how I should be specifying them.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem, did you find any solution?

Comment: I never found a solution. It may have been a problem on the server end, as discussed below, but unfortunately I I was pulled off that project before any progress could be made.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [KeepAliveHttpsTransportSE](https://github.com/mosabua/ksoap2-android/blob/master/ksoap2-j2se/src/main/java/org/ksoap2/transport/KeepAliveHttpsTransportSE.java) from the [ksaop2-android](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/) project. It works just fine for me.

And confirm that the url exposes the service just fine on the browser on the device just to check availability in terms of proxies and so on.

From you code most likely this is causing the problems:

```
 HttpTransportSE t = new HttpTransportSE(mUrl);
    AndroidInsecureKeepAliveHttpsTransportSE androidTransport = 
new AndroidInsecureKeepAliveHttpsTransportSE("XXXXXXXX.net", 80, mUrl, 50000);
```

Do not use one transport within another that way. Instead use the constructor or AndroidInsecureKeepAliveHttpsTransportSE of whatever only. The constructors do some initialization and if you reuse them it will bugger up most likely.

Comment: Hi Manfred, thanks for your answer. I'm having trouble checking if it works on the browser - it looks like it's loading, and asks me to accept the certificate, but then gives a blank page. Do you know if this is a good or a bad sign?

Comment: probably a bad sign.. since there is some sort of certificate problem.. there are some links on the wiki that link to articles that detail more about this stuff

Comment: Sorry man, I was checking through my stuff there, not sure when this was accepted in the first place. I never got your suggestion to work, my issue remains unsolved. I wasn't sure if I should be leaving the answer as accepted, when the issue remains. I had to move onto other matters since but I'll be returning to the secure webservice thing soon.

Answer (score 0):

This site: http://obtao.com/blog/2013/09/how-to-use-wsse-in-android-app/
explains how to generate a nonce, encode it, and include it in the header.  If you copy the nonce from soapui, it should fail on the back-end, as the whole point of the nonce is to prevent such a replay.  You need to generate your own, as shown in example referenced.